# Почему не работает find_library() внутри foreach()?

Tags: cmake

**Код:**

```
foreach (item avformat avcodec avfilter)

    message("${item}")
    
    find_library(ff_lib
        NAMES
            ${item}
        PATH_SUFFIXES
            ffmpeg-4.3-win64-dev/lib/
        REQUIRED
    )

    message("${ff_lib}")
    
    set(FFmpeg ${FFmpeg} ${ff_lib})
    
    unset(ff_lib)
    
endforeach ()

message("${FFmpeg}")
```

**Вывод:**

```
avformat
C:/Users/me/Desktop/ffmpeg-4.3-win64-dev/lib/avformat.lib
avcodec
C:/Users/me/Desktop/ffmpeg-4.3-win64-dev/lib/avformat.lib
avfilter
C:/Users/me/Desktop/ffmpeg-4.3-win64-dev/lib/avformat.lib
C:/Users/me/Desktop/ffmpeg-4.3-win64-dev/lib/avformat.lib;C:/Users/me/Desktop/ffmpeg-4.3-win64-dev/lib/avformat.lib;C:/Users/me/Desktop/ffmpeg-4.3-win64-dev/lib/avformat.lib
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
```

**PS:** т.е. переменная `ff_lib` не перезаписывается даже после `unset(ff_lib)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Нашёл костыль](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36757842/cmake-use-foreach-and-find-library-to-return-full-path-of-libraries) в англоязычном StackOverflow. Оказывается `find_library()` устанавливает кэшированную переменную, которую нельзя удалить. Вот так работает:

```
foreach (item avformat avcodec avfilter)

    set(ff_lib ff_lib-NOTFOUND)

    find_library(ff_lib
        NAMES
            ${item}
        PATH_SUFFIXES
            ffmpeg-4.3-win64-dev/lib/
        REQUIRED
    )

    set(FFmpeg ${FFmpeg} ${ff_lib})

endforeach ()
```

Comment: Почему костыль? Так и надо. Разве что, можно `unset(XXX CACHE)` использовать.